# multiline textbox starting with a special character in each line

Tags: vb.net, textbox

Simple question, i have a textbox which may be multilined (it might not be depending on user input) and is referred to as i:

```
dim i as string
i = textbox1.text
```

I need to insert a " ' " at the start of every line in. Is it possible?

After that, save it to a .txt file.

Best regards

Comment: @MikkoViitala Could you give an example?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service...

Answer (score 2):

Replace all occurences of `vbCrLf` maybe?

```
Dim i As String
i = TextBox1.Text

i = "'" + i.Replace(vbCrLf, vbCrLf + "'")
Console.WriteLine(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Test this:

```
Dim i As String
Dim sb As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder

With Me.TextBox1   ' .Multiline = True
    i = .Text

    For y = 0 To .Lines.Count - 1
        sb.Append("'")
        sb.AppendLine(.Lines(y))
    Next
End With

Dim Desktop As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim fileFullPath As String

With My.Computer

    Desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)
    fileName = "TextFile.txt"
    fileFullPath = .FileSystem.CombinePath(Desktop, fileName)

    Try
        .FileSystem.WriteAllText(fileFullPath, sb.ToString, append:=False)

        MsgBox(String.Format("File:{0}{0}{1}{2}{0}{0}saved successfully!", vbNewLine, vbTab, fileFullPath))
        Shell("notepad.exe " & fileFullPath, AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
Dim i As String = TextBox1.Text
i = "'" & i.Replace(vbCrLf, vbCrLf + "'")  
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\yourtextfile.txt",i)
```